# Optimize jQuery.fx.interval depending on browser speed

Tags: jquery, performance

I've noticed significant differences in how my site's jQuery animations perform on Chrome vs. IE7, desktop vs. old laptop, processor speed, and so on. I'm toying with using jQuery's interval function:

```
jQuery.fx.interval = 20;
```

Is it possible to **dynamically set an optimal interval** depending on the performance on the user's browser and computer?

If adapting to actual performance is not possible, would it be a good next best solution to slow down the interval just for older browsers like <=IE7?

Comment: What's the reason for the -1?

Comment: I'm trying to animate a translucent full page div which will act like a lightbox with a 500px height div sliding down from above the top of the page until it's top is 0px. Ramping up the jQuery.fx.interval makes this smoother. But at what cost?

I found this question through Google and was hoping that this question would be answered but apparently not.